# latex macros in textmate?

Tags: text-editor, textmate

I'm new to textmate and I want to use it to write latex.

I have many macros when i was using my previous latex-editor, I'm wondering how i can put it into textmate. If I saved something as a .sty file, where shall I put it?

Thanks

Comment: why are you switching to textmate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bundles are how you customize TextMate. There's an [official one](http://github.com/textmate/latex.tmbundle), and I thought there was an experimental one somewhere.

As far as putting your own macros into TextMate, the in the menu bar: Bundles -> Bundle Editor -> Show Bundle Editor. Here you can put

- commands (shell scripts - aka anything you can trigger via a #! line) that do something
- macros (thing UI macros: select this menu item, do this find, etc)
- snippets (blocks of text that you define)
- languages (define your own language - aka: "this special thing should show up in the function popup)
- preferences (kind of work hand in hand with languages)